# Replace thousands/decimal separator in input[type="number"]?

Tags: html

Is there a native way of  defining thousands/decimal separator in input[type="number"]?

**What I want**

I want to define, what separators are displayed in this kind of input, and not let the browser decide.

By default, if you set the browser language to "German", the decimal separator will be a comma (,) and the thounds separator a point (.). Setting the browser to "English", will change them. What is of course correct, but as my application is english language only, it would make sense to always use the english separators.

The only thing I can imagine is, to define a pattern, but this would only apply on the validation.

Comment: You do not have control over the user's regional settings. You could, I suppose, use keyboard events to try and force the issue, but you are only going to annoy your user.

Comment: What browser supports this on `<input type="number">` fields? Chrome and Firefox don't seem to display any separators.

Comment: **Short answer** No!

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Chrome does support this: https://jsfiddle.net/bdx743yp/ The advantage of this type is, that you are able to increment and decrement the number values with arrow up and down.

Comment: Oh I see, only for the decimal separators, not for the thousands separators.